# Where does the Gini coefficient come from?

Tags: classification, roc, gini

I understand what a ROC curve is. However, I do not understand the Gini coefficient in the context of binary classification.

All the resources I have checked state that $Gini = 1 - (2 \times AUC_{ROC})$.

How is this equality derived? As an economist, it troubles me to think of a Gini coefficient in this context.

Comment: Aside: Gini, Corrado.  (1912) "On the measure of concentration with especial reference to income and wealth" Reprinted in *Memorie di metodologica statistica* (Ed. Pizetti E, Salvemini, T). Rome: Libreria Eredi Virgilio Veschi (1955).

Comment: Watch out: the name Gini coefficient has been applied to at least three different measures. Trust equations used, not names.

Comment: @NickCox Is that right? Can you recommend a good "Hey look at these three different formal measures!"-type article or blog?

Comment: Not readily. The main point is that there are literatures that don’t really touch, notably income inequality and CART.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's complicated. It appears that the Gini coefficient based on the ROC curve was invented by [analogy](https://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/10.1002/(SICI)1097-0258(19990228)18:4%3C455::AID-SIM44%3E3.0.CO;2-A) with the economic Gini coefficient based on the Lorenz curve. It's not a perfect analogy – e.g., the Lorenz curve is necessarily convex and the ROC curve is only necessarily monotone. They do happen to be [the same in some situations](https://royalsocietypublishing.org/doi/10.1098/rsos.140280)

Also, if you have fitted probabilities $\hat p_i$ for each individual, and you have a well-calibrated model (ie, $\hat p_i$ really does estimate $P[Y=1|X=x_i]$), there is some relationship between the two in concept.  If you have a well-calibrated model, you can summarise how well it predicts by considering the variability in the predictions – since, *ex hypothesi*, different predictions for different people reflects genuine discriminatory power.  So, you can look at the $\hat p$ and ask how unequal they are, with more inequality implying better discrimination.

However, the simple relationship between AUC and the economic Gini coefficient doesn't hold [in general](http://www.weizmann.ac.il/math/gideon/sites/math.gideon/files/uploads/AUC_Metron%20May%202019%20v4.pdf).